# Flask directory Structure

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-login

I have flask project which work on presently. (below)

[image: Flask project directory]

When I run this project using command

```
python run.py
```

I get following error.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "run.py", line 1, in 
>       from site import app
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'app'

**run.py**

```
from site import app
import os

app.secret_key = os.urandom(24)
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug="True")
# app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from .views import app
from .models import db


db.create_all()

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:password@localhost:5432/db'
app.config['SECURITY_REGISTERABLE'] = True
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from .models import User, db
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
from flask.ext.security import login_required

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/profile/<email>')
@login_required
def user_index(email):
    user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
    return render_template('profile.html', user=user)


@app.route('/post_user', methods=['POST'])
def post_user():
    if request.form["action"] == "submit_btn":
        user = User(request.form['username'], request.form['email'])
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

**models.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, UserMixin, RoleMixin

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
mail = Mail()
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    active = db.Column(db.Boolean())
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))
```

What should be the directory structure? Also how should I import the models and views in order to make the server work?

Please tell me if you need any other info, thanks in advance.

Comment: If `app` is not defined in the init module at `from .views import app`, then your error clearly states `app` can't be found because it doesn't exist

Comment: ok, so how should I place the `app` in order to work this? I have placed `app` inside the `views.py`. I would really appreciate a better to manage views and models in the flask project.

Comment: Where are you defining your: app = Flask(__name__) ?

Comment: There should be an app variable defined in the site folder, not within views. Views is only for defining the URLs of your site. If you edit your question to include the file where you actually define the app variable, then it'll be more clear what you're trying to do

Comment: @lapinkoira inside the views.py

Comment: I have mixed it up badly, I know. I have `app = Flask(__name__)` in both `views.py` and `models.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename the site's name so python dont try to import the site standard library, also is better to define the app inside the **init**.py file: [Docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/packages/)

Comment: Yeah... try, from site import views and then views.app is your app, that's why it's suggested to initialize the app in the __init_.py, it looks better

Comment: Well, actually, my example should work, which python version are you using?

Comment: Ahhh shit, can you rename your site's application? you are importing this module instead your app https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html

Comment: I shifted the app to init.py and I am using python 3.5

Comment: Okay, I changed the name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108294/discussion-between-rahul-parashar-and-lapinkoira).